# Rewrite a whole website urls

Tags: php, url, button, rewriting

I currently have a website with many pages like this (some pages have more parameters than others):

`http://www.website.com/page.php?parameter1=value1&parameters2=value2`

I'd like to get URLs like this:

`http://www.website.com/page/parameter1/value1/parameter2/value2`

I know how to write a rule to get the re-written URL to show the page behind the "true" URL, the problem is that it's too long to change all my pages (links, buttons, header redirection, etc. in the PHP code). Is there a way to do it automatically? How should I have done it when coding the website?

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends with what you would call automatic. Most php frameworks have built in routing and can handle slugs and parameters.

A simple framework that you could use for this is [PHP Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/). The first codeblock on the website is an example of how routes can ben handled with it.

Comment: Thank you. I learned how to use the Symfony Framework and now use the routing system, it solved my problem